# pointer of pointer of char in c, assignment crashes

Tags: c, pointers

I have a pointer of pointer to store lines I read from a file;

```
char **lines;
```

And I'm assigning them like this :

```
line_no=0;
*(&lines[line_no++])=buffer;
```

But it crashes why ?

According to my logic the `&` should give the pointer of zeroth index, then `*var=value`, that's how to store value in pointer. Isn't it ?

Here is my current complete code :

```
void read_file(char const *name,int len)
{
    int line_no=0;
    FILE* file;
    int buffer_length = 1024;
    char buffer[buffer_length];

    file = fopen(name, "r");

    while(fgets(buffer, buffer_length, file)) {
        printf("---%s", buffer);
        ++line_no;
        if(line_no==0)
        {
            lines = (char**)malloc(sizeof(*lines) * line_no);
        }
        else
        {
            lines = (char**)realloc(lines,sizeof(*lines) * line_no);
        }
        lines[line_no-1] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(buffer));
        lines[line_no-1]=buffer;
        printf("-------%s--------\n", *lines[line_no-1]);
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: It crashes because you didn't allocate memories for the pointer.

Comment: Please copy entire code and clarify your question.

Comment: Why are you taking the address and then dereferencing? Together they do nothing. This crashes because the lines array is never allocated.

Comment: i have updated the que @Majkl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just a pointer, nothing more. You need to allocate memory using `malloc()`.

Actually, you need first to allocate memory for pointers, then allocate memory for strings.

*N* lines, each *M* characters long:

```c
char** lines = malloc(sizeof(*lines) * N);
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    lines[i] = malloc(sizeof(*(lines[i])) * M);
}
```

You are also taking an address and then immediately dereference it - something like`*(&foo)` makes little to no sense.

---

## For updated code

Oh, there is so much wrong with that code...

1. You need to include `stdlib.h` to use `malloc()`
2. `lines` is undeclared. The `char** lines` is missing before loop
3. `if` in loop checks whether `line_no` is `0`. If it is, then it allocates `lines`. The problem is, variable `line_no` is `0` - `sizeof(*lines)` times 0 is still zero. It allocates no memory.
4. But! There is `++line_no` at the beginning of the loop, therefore `line_no` is never 0, so `malloc()` isn't called at all.
5. `lines[line_no-1] = buffer;` - it doesn't copy from `buffer` to `lines[line_no-1]`, it just assigns pointers. To copy strings in C you need to use `strcpy()`
6. `fgets()` adds new line character at the end of buffer - you probably want to remove it: `buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';`
7. Argument `len` is never used.
8. `char buffer[buffer_length];` - don't use [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)
9. It would be better to increment `line_no` at the end of the loop instead of constantly calculating `line_no-1`
10. In C, casting result of `malloc()` isn't mandatory
11. There is no check, if opening file failed
12. You aren't freeing the memory

Considering all of this, I quickly "corrected" it to such state:

```c
void read_file(char const* name)
{
    FILE* file = fopen(name, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    int buffer_length = 1024;
    char buffer[1024];

    char** lines = malloc(0);

    int line_no = 0;
    while (fgets(buffer, buffer_length, file)) {
        buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';
        printf("---%s\n", buffer);
        lines = realloc(lines, sizeof (*lines) * (line_no+1));
        lines[line_no] = malloc(sizeof (*lines[line_no]) * buffer_length);
        strcpy(lines[line_no], buffer);
        printf("-------%s--------\n", lines[line_no]);
        ++line_no;
    }

    fclose(file);

    for (int i = 0; i < line_no; ++i) {
        free(lines[i]);
    }
    free(lines);
}
```

Comment: can you check my question again ??

Comment: really appreciate it, thanks a lot.. just one more question ```for(int i=0;(lines+i);i++){         printf("%s\n", *(lines+i));}``` if write this to read all those lines, it prints all line and crashes.. can you tell me why ??

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have a couple of errors here:

1. lines array is not declared
2. Your allocation is wrong
3. I don't understand this line, it is pointless to allocate something multiplying it by zero

   if( line_no == 0 )
   {

   lines = (char**)malloc(sizeof(*lines) * line_no);

   }
4. You shouldn't allocate array with just one element and constantly reallocate it. It is a bad practice, time-consuming, and can lead to some bigger problems later.
5. I recommend you to check this [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) for malloc casting.

You could write something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void read_file(char const *name)
{
    int line_no = 0, arr_size = 10;
    int buffer_length = 1024;
    char buffer[buffer_length];
    char **lines;
    
    FILE* file;
    
    lines = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 10);
    
    file = fopen(name, "r");

    while(fgets(buffer, buffer_length, file)) {
        buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';
        printf("---%s", buffer);
        ++line_no;
        
        if(line_no == arr_size)
        {
            arr_size += 10;
            
            lines = realloc(lines, sizeof(char*) * arr_size);
        }
        
        lines[line_no-1] = malloc(sizeof(buffer));
        lines[line_no-1] = buffer;
        printf("-------%s--------\n", lines[line_no-1]);
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

PS, `fgets()` also takes the `'\n'` char at the end, in order to prevent this you can write the following line: `buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';`